# Problem in sending and receiving sms (Kotlin Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, sms, smsmanager

LoginActivity.kt:

```
if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        || checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        || checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        requestPermissions(
            arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS,
                android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS), PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        )
    }

signInBtn.setOnClickListener {

fun sendSms(phoneNumber: String, message: String) {
    val smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null)
   }
}

sendSms("50004000151398","OK")
```

the main problem is this warning : `getDefault() : SmsManager! is deprecated`

I have tested some answers I’ve read :

```
val smsManager = getSystemService(SmsManager::class.java)
```

OR

```
val smsManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(SmsManager::class.java)
```

**None of them workes** ; after running app with all these solutions, the app crashes (app stops)

ERROR:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10185 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
```

I’ve added permissions in Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#SEND_SMS) it is not enough just to add android.permission.SEND_SMS
to manifest, because its protection level is dangerous.

You have to ask for this permission
[at runtime](https://source.android.com/docs/core/permissions/runtime_perms).